# TypedValue.applyDimension() in Android 11 return strange value

Tags: android

I used this code to calculate the size of a PDF page.

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int pageWidth = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM, 210, displayMetrics);
int pageHeight = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM, 297, displayMetrics);
```

The returned values were in the range of 4000-7000.

However, starting from Android 10, the TypedValue.applyDimension() returns values in the range of 15-30.

What changed?
I need to apply those sizes to a LinearLayout.

Comment: That method doesn't seem to have changed at all since the very early days of Android. How are you obtaining `displayMetrics`? Are you sure you're interpreting your observations correctly? I haven't run any tests yet, or anything.

Comment: Hello, I've updated the question. I have debugged the app in the new Android API 30 emulator and in previous devices to compare the results.

Comment: I am not reproducing the described results on an Android 10 emulator. I'll have to get an API level 30 one going later.

Comment: Why are you using `DisplayMetrics` for code that, in the end, is not being used for a display?

Comment: I used them to call "measure" and "layout" with the correct value in pixel on the views I inflate. I've inserted the size of the drawn views in mm on the XML files used to populate the PDF. (I insert multiple views at runtime in a layout that is then printed on the PDF)

Comment: Confirmed on the API level 30 emulator. It looks like the x and y DPIs aren't being set correctly in the system properties, however that's done, exactly. I'm getting values of 2.75 for both, which is way off.

Comment: Yep, here we go: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158747366. Somebody just reported it yesterday. Now we wait...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this has been fixed in the latest API 30 emulator. (build RPB2.200611.012)